# Generar una lista con bucle

Tags: python, python-3.x

quisiera hacer una lista en la que se genere un bucle tal que

```
x = 1

while x <= 20:
print(int(x))
x = x * 3.23
```

Algo asi pero que entren todos los resultados en una sola lista y sin decimales

Algo de este estilo:

```
#quiero esto:
[1, 3, 10]

#pero tengo esto:
1
3
10
```

*Si hay alguna otra forma de hacer una lista con un patron asi tambien me serviría*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buruso, entendiendo tu pregunta, yo lo haría de esta forma:

```
lista = []   # Creamos el Array
x = 1

while x <= 20:
    lista.append(round(x))  # Aqui agregas al array, el contenido de la variable x con redondeo
    x = x * 3.23
print(lista)
```

Creo un array llamado `lista` (por colocarle un nombre) y con `lista.append(round(x))` voy agregando elementos a ese array pero redondeando el resultado..

Comment: Muchas gracias, es justo lo que necesitaba